# problems with Firebase .childChanged in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use Firebase to hold a users profile info. Because you cannot listen to a Storage Reference, I added a child to the database that changes every time the user changes their profile pic (just a randomly generated uuidString . I verified that it is indeed changing in firebase and the new child is in the same location as the others. whenever a user changes their info, a user that is viewing that profile should see the change so I tested this. Even though the child is changing, there is no change to the profile pic. However, if the user changes another piece of info, I tested it with bio, the profile will update, along with the latest profile pic. A mid-debug version of the code is below:

```
    let ref = DatabaseReference.allUsers.reference()
    let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: (user.uid))

    query.observe(.childChanged, with: { snapshot in
        let user = User(dictionary: snapshot.value as! [String : Any])
        self.user = user
        self.bio.text = user.bio
        self.user?.fullName = user.fullName
        self.user?.instagram = user.instagram
        self.user?.facebook = user.facebook
        self.user?.phone = user.phone
        self.user?.email = user.email

    })

    //let ref2 = DatabaseReference.users(uid: user.uid).reference()
    //let query2 = ref2.child("updatePic")

    query.observe(.childChanged, with: { snapshot in
        let user = User(dictionary: snapshot.value as! [String : Any])

        self.user?.downloadProfilePicture { [weak self] (image, error) in
            self?.profilePicture.image = image
            let profilePictureKey = "\(user.uid)-headerImage"
            self?.cache?.setObject(image, forKey: profilePictureKey)
        }
    })
```

So far I've scratched my head because I have no idea what I could be missing. Basically, it's not recognizing that the child was changed even though I am watching it change before my eyes. Any ideas?

update: Is it possible that the profile photo has not finished being updated at the time the childChanged is triggered and therefore the same photo is being downloaded? this is my current code for changing the photo:

```
    extension FIRImage {
func saveProfileImage(_ userUID: String, _ completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    let resizedImage = image.resized()
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage, 1.0)

    ref = StorageReference.profileImages.reference().child(userUID)
    downloadLink = ref.description

    ref.put(imageData!, metadata: nil) {
        (metaData, error) in
        completion(error)
    }
    updateProfilePic(userUID)
    }
    func updateProfilePic(_ userUID: String) {
    var randomString = UUID().uuidString
    let ref = DatabaseReference.users(uid: userUID).reference()
    ref.child("updatePic").setValue(randomString)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to put my updateProfilePic inside the completion block of the saveProfileImage function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is the cause of your problem, but you should definitely consider storing your users in a structure like this:

```
users: {
  uid1: {
    name: "Sudacris"
    profilePic: "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/60fa08515b157ef927d885a4217c0f76?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"
  },
  uid1: {
    name: "Frank van Puffelen"
    profilePic: "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/12d378e6a9788ab9c94bbafe242b82b4?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG"
  }
}
```

This allows you to look up a specific user without needing a query. You just do a direct lookup:

```
let ref = DatabaseReference.allUsers.reference()
let userRef = ref.child(user.uid)

userRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
   let user = User(dictionary: snapshot.value as! [String : Any])
   ...
```

Comment: Yeah it doesn't really help. That's like if you were a mechanic and I took my VW in to you and you said "you should probably have a Mercedes instead"

Comment: @Sudacris No. It's more like, if he were a Google Engineer and you took your code to him and he said "Here's a dumb-simple solution to your problem instead"